# ¿Como logro obtener el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado y mostrarlo? LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, laravel, ajax, stored-procedure

espero alguien pueda orientarme, tengo el siguiente problema.
Hice un procedimiento almacenado de la base de datos que estoy utilizando.

[image: Procedimiento almacenado:]

Cuando lo ejecuto me lo muestra de la siguiente forma:

[image: Resultado del procedimiento almacenado]

Ahora, el problema viene, cuando trato de mostrar estos resultados en una vista en LARAVEL. solo me muestra el primer resultado.

[image: Muestra del resultado, solo muestra el primer resultado]

uso un script utilizando Ajax para mostrar la información
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta el archivo dashboard.ajax.php que esta llamando el script
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El dashboard.controlador.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modelo haciendo call al procedimiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la conexion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando entro al archivo directamente me muestra solo un dato

Y bueno este es mi problema. Si me comentan que inicie el php artisan serve en laravel, pues cuando lo utilizo no me trae ni el primer resultado.

Quisiera ver si alguien puede ayudarme con esto. ya intente cambiar la manera en que tengo la conexión pero no me funciona.

Comment: Por favor no pongas tu código como imagen y mejor compartelo como texto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo mediante el query builder, para ser más especifico mediante [select](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements).

Sin parametros:

```
DB::select('EXEC stored_procedure_name')
```

Con parametros:

```
DB::select('exec stored_procedure_name(?,?,...)',array($param1,$param2,...));
```

Comment: OBS: es raro utilizar procedimientos de almacenado en laravel, ya que el framework es bastante completo y mediante sus propias funciones permite una compatibilidad con múltiples motores de base de datos sin tener que estar modificando el SQL luego. Para mantener esta compatibilidad te recomiendo revisar el [ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent), y los [eventos](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events). En base a lo anterior replantear si tu código realmente debería estar en un sp.